# Text To Columns VBA Destination onto new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a problem with Excel VBA Text To Columns. Apparently the function is fixated on putting the destination on the same sheet when I want it to be on a new sheet.

```
Worksheets("RawData").Columns(ID).TextToColumns Destination:=Worksheets("Regular").Columns("C"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=True, _
    OtherChar:="(", _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Apparently this will just dump it on Column C of raw data rather than the worksheet of "Regular" where i want it to be.

Comment: why not just copy data to `Worksheets("Regular").Columns("C")` and then make `TextToColumns`?

Comment: That has occurred to me but I was wondering if there was some nicer way of doing it that wont affect the content of the original sheet I'm working with.

Comment: As I see, it wont affect the content of `Worksheets("RawData")` (result would be the same as if your code would be working). btw, you can't make text to columns with destination on another sheet.

Comment: That is what I'm trying to do but the out put will just go to Column C of "raw data" rather than the column C of "regular" where i want it to be.

Comment: forget about your current code. Write new one. Sth like this should work: **Step1 :** copy data from one worksheet to another - `Worksheets("RawData").Columns(ID).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Regular").Columns("C")`. **Step2 :** now you have copy of your data in sheet *"Regular"*. Make *"TextToColumns"* : `Worksheets("Regular").Columns("C").TextToColumns Destination:=Worksheets("Regular").Columns("C") ...` (note, now text to columns using only *"Regular"* sheet)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be using string manipulation directly. Assuming you want the colon to be your delimiter in the text to column command:

```
dim i as integer
dim j as integer
dim strTemp as string
dim arrString() as string

for i = 1 to 'number of rows in your first sheet
    strTemp = cells(i, 1)
    arrStrings = strings.split(strTemp, ",")
    for j = 1 to ubound(arrStrings)
        sheet2.cells(i, j) = arrStrings(j)
    next j
next i
```